# Facebook graph API group permanent access token for admin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been searching for any way to get the permanent access token for a group, as FB API provides a method for Facebook Page.

I am the admin of the group, and from my app I want any method to get the permanent access token.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no permanent Group Token, there is no Group Token at all. You can only use an Extended User Token, it is valid for 60 days. Of course you need to refresh it with user interaction, there is no way to auto-refresh it.

More information about all existing Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: thanks for rely, is there any way to make user token permanent?

Comment: i have added 2 links about tokens